# How Is Network Activate Different From Activate (by Implementation)?

Tags: plugins, multisite, customization

How is plugin network activate different from normal activation by implementation? What is done/not done in network activation that is done/not done in activation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Network activation will activate a plugin for every site in a network whereas regular activation will only activate a plugin for the site you're currently on. As far as implementation goes, there is one other important difference:

If your plugin is built to do something when it's activated (via [`register_activation_hook()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_activation_hook/)), this will fire automatically when you activate a plug-in normally, but it will *not* fire for a network-activated plugin until you visit the admin screen for each blog.

So if major database updates are tied in to `register_activation_hook()` they won't occur until you log in to the other sites.

Comment: The super-admin or the admin should visit the http://site.com/subblog/wp-admin/ URL for plugins' activation hooks to be executed? Or do you mean that they must go to the plugin page of the sub blog and then click on the "activate" link?

Comment: They must visit the `wp-admin` url for the plug-ins' activation hooks to be executed.

Comment: @EAMann is there a programmatic way to do the same thing? I have hundreds of blogs.

Comment: Not easily. I'd recommend storing a version string in the DB for each site and checking to see if things are installed upon first use.